# Related search for lookup. I have 3 different obj, Opportunity, Brand__c and Corporate__c

Tags: relationships, developer, admin

Flow is, 1st I register Corporate(Independently) and then brand. Each brand is associated to one corporate. 
In opportunity I want to choose Corporate which is a direct lookup and then Brand. Question is: Searched brand should be related to selected corporate.(Only related brands to selected Corporate should appear in search)
How can I achieve that with standard functionality or using Apex ?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Lookup filter`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) in Brand field inside Opportunity object.

Inside the lookup filter set the filter like: brand field > corporateId with operator equal to a field reference of Opportunity > corporateId field.